# Require in react can't resolve path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to use tracking-js library in my project I'm using react but I dont know if I'm doing anything wrong but keep showing that the module is not found, I already check my `package.json` and the module install. So this is how I require the module:

```
const tracking = require("tracking");
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are many things that could be going wrong; are you using a bundling tool (webpack, browserify, etc)? If so, they may be misconfigured, and you ought to post that configuration.

Answer (score 0):

For node, including node-based build tools, first make sure that the module is present. Keep in mind that `require` does not care about the `package.json` of your app, only about the module files being present.

1. Check if `node_modules/tracking` is present.
2. Make sure the "main" JS file can be found. If there's a `node_modules/tracking/package.json` file, see if it has a `main` property and if the file it references exists. If there is no `main` property, make sure there's an `index.js` in the root of the module directory.
3. If all this is fine and you're getting the module not found error at runtime in *client-side* JavaScript, then your bundling config may be incorrect, and your webpack/browserify/whatever config will have to be scrutinized for bugs.

Comment: Thank you Jacob I check the module that I was installing and they don't have a main property I think that was the issue. so that means that I have to require the full path to the file ?

Comment: Not if there's an `index.js`; that's the default `main` file. If `index.js` also doesn't exist, then maybe your install is corrupt and you should try reinstalling. If it always installs like that, then the module is badly published, and you should open a bug.